# General rules for forming groups for analyses

Tags: data-transformation, bioinformatics, group-differences

I am analysing EEG data.

I have data from 19 electrodes from 25 participants divided into two groups (11 and 14 subjects). I asked my student to compare these two groups with some statistical test.

Surprisingly, he calculated means for every electrode (giving two groups with 19 numbers in each).

I suppose that it is more valid to calculate means for each participant (resulting in two groups with 11 and 14 numbers).

Who is right? Or are we both right?

What are the general rules for forming groups for analyses?

Comment: Does each of the 25 patients have 19 electrodes? In that case, I'd imagine you'd have two groups with $19 \cdot 11$ and $19 \cdot 25$ points according to the student's strategy. Can you clarify the data structure a bit more?

Comment: Yes. Each of the 25 patients have 19 electrodes. Lets imagine two tables (two groups) with 11 and 14 columns(participants) and 19 rows (electrodes) in each. I calculate mean for every columns, my student for rows.

Comment: Well, if your goal is to compare the two groups (as it appears it is), I don't see what sense averaging the rows could make. Regarding column averaging, is there important information lost by averaging across the electrodes?

Comment: Thank you for attention. Of course some information lost, like spatial structure, but I understand that I can compare this two table row by row. Or use ANOVA. I interesting with sense of my student's method.

Comment: If you have got this from working in a hospital environment, then this would be classified as research and you should have people available who can provide statistical advice as part of their job. While students are encouraged to learn on the job, the use of patient data in research implies an ethical duty to use it responsibly and effectively.  In the absence of such support, I would suggest researching the relevant literature to see how such data is normally analysed, though that does not mean that there may not be some room for improvement.